# Typo3 Gridelements - setup not working

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, tx-gridelements

I'm using Typo3 7.6.10 with Gridelements 7.0.5. I'm trying to wrap the gridelement output with the following code but the wrapping is not working. Both files are loaded. The 2-cols-50-50 element is available in the backend and the static gridelements template is loaded. The content of the gridelement is displayed without the wrap defined in the gridelements.ts file.

I would be happy for every help.

tsconfig.ts

```
tx_gridelements {
    overruleRecords = 1
    setup {
        2-cols-50-50 {
            title = 2-Columns
            description = 2-columns contentelement
            topLevelLayout = 0
            config {
                colCount = 2
                rowCount = 1
                rows {
                    1 {
                        columns {
                            1 {
                                name = Left
                                colPos = 11
                            }
                            2 {
                                name = Right
                                colPos = 12
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

gridelements.ts

```
tt_content.gridelements_pi1.20.10.setup >
tt_content.gridelements_pi1.20.10.setup {
    2-cols-50-50 < lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup
    2-cols-50-50 {
        columns {
            11 < .default
            11.wrap = <div class="left">|</div>
            12 < .default
            12.wrap = <div class="right">|</div>
        }
        wrap = <div class="well">|</div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `"2-cols-50-50"` you should use `2-cols-50-50`, so please remove the `"`

Comment: Also without the "" it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

I found the mistake. The static gridelements template has to be included before the extension template. Otherwise the static template overwrites `tt_content.gridelements_pi1`.